# App crashes after download of 6th image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem, need help.
I have a table, on cell I have horizontal scroll with images. Images are downloaded from internet.
When i download the 6th image, my app crashes.
For async upload I use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

```
  -(void) fastCreateImage
   {
int tempID = self.currentPageNow;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.2f * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    if(tempID==self.currentPageNow)
    {
        NSUInteger objIdx = [self.imageViews indexOfObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempID]];
        if(objIdx != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"WAS CACHED!!!!!!");
        }
        else
        {
             UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 193.5f)];

    NSString *urlInString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploads/gallery/hotels/%@",webSite,[self.urlGarbage objectAtIndex:self.currentPageNow]];
            SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
            [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlInString]
                            delegate:self
                             options:0
                             success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached)
             {
                 myImageView.image = image;
                 [[self.views objectAtIndex:tempID] addSubview:myImageView];
                 [self.imageViews addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tempID]];
                 NSLog(@"LOADED IMG");
             }
                             failure:nil];
            [myImageView release];
        }


    }
});
 }
```

Comment: Could it be that you mean DOWNLOAD instead of UPLOAD? You're telling "my app is crashed". What kind of crash? Post the exception text from the console. Did you enable Zombies for debugging?

Comment: sorry, i mean download image. I got message Received memory warning. NSZombieEnabled = YES, but i cant track errors

Comment: mb i should use [manager release]?

Comment: If you receive a memory warning, either the images you're downloading are **really** big and consume too much memory, or other apps consuming memory are running (try restarting your device). Do not release `manager`, you are using a singleton instance (`shared Manager`) which exists only once. Look in your code for calls to `alloc` and make sure, each alloc is paired with a `release`.

Comment: How big are the images you're loading? What is their size (in kB) and which dimension (x, y in pixels) do they have?

Comment: i try download 690 kb by image. its very much ? :)

Comment: As I already asked, please tell the dimensions of the image in pixels (x, y). If the image is compressed well and loads into memory, it will be decompressed and can become quite large. Depending on the color depth a maximum of (width * height * 4) bytes of memory is used. Please calculate this for each of your images and sum it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting a memory warning, I guess your images are too large to fit in memory. An image uses a maximum of `width*height*4` (depending on color depth) of your memory. Calculate this memory requirement for each of your images to see if this is the problem.